# How to alter table add column with named default constraint and named foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql-server

I have two existing tables (TableA and TableB) and I need to add a new column to TableA that has a foreign key to TableB and has a default value that is not null... and both these constraints need to be named. How can I do this?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Adding both constraints in one statement wasn't as easy as I thought it would be and there didn't seem to be many examples out there (at least I wasn't able to find any very easily), so I thought I'd share how I did it here and maybe someone can suggest a better way?

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] ADD
    [New Column Name] [Column Type] 
    CONSTRAINT [constraint name] DEFAULT ([default value]) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [constraint name] FOREIGN KEY ([New Column Name]) 
    REFERENCES [Other Table] ([Foreign ID])
```

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD
    myNewColumn BIGINT 
    CONSTRAINT myNamedConstraint_df default (1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT myNamedConstraint_fk FOREIGN KEY (myNewColumn)
    REFERENCES tableB (tableBPrimaryKeyID)
```

Comment: In MySQL, we need to add `ADD` prefix before `CONSTRAINT`.
`ADD  CONSTRAINT myNamedConstraint_df default (1) NOT NULL,`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's also common to land here from the question how to add a column with a constraint in **MySQL**, I'll add an answer for that here too:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE tableB (id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id));
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD
    myNewColumn BIGINT DEFAULT 42 NOT NULL,
    ADD CONSTRAINT myNamedConstraint_fk FOREIGN KEY (myNewColumn) REFERENCES tableB (id);
```

I think there is no way to also name the `DEFAULT` constraint in MySQL as it's done for `sql-server` in the other answer, correct me if I'm wrong.